# How to read a file during training in AWS SageMaker?

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to train a custom tensorflow model, using AWS SageMaker. Thus, in the `model_fn` method, that I should provide, I want to be able to read an external file. I've uploaded the file to S3 and try to read like below:

```
BUCKET_PATH = 's3://<bucket_name>/data/<prefix>/'

def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    # Load vocabulary
    vocab_path = os.path.join(BUCKET_PATH, 'vocab.pkl')
    with open(vocab_path, 'rb') as f:
        vocab = pickle.load(f)
    n_vocab = len(vocab)
    ...
```

I get an `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

How can I read this file during training?

Comment: I used boto3 to download files from S3 onto the training instance.

Do you need to access that file from the endpoint instance as well?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think pickle.load can ping an S3 bucket. You can either keep the data in the python notebook path or download it using boto3 client.

Moreover, you'd probably not want to download it in model_fn. That would be called for each epoch. Generally data is loaded and prepared in the train_input_fn.